The funchook library does not work during normal operation
I use the funchook library hook PyUnicode_Format function, and my code looks like this,
https://github.com/kubo/funchook
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <funchook.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Original PyUnicode_Format function pointer
static PyObject *(*orig_PyUnicode_Format)(PyObject *format, PyObject *args) = NULL;

// Hooked version of PyUnicode_Format
static PyObject *hooked_PyUnicode_Format(PyObject *format, PyObject *args) {
    printf("PyUnicode_Format is called with format: %s\n", PyUnicode_AsUTF8(format));

    // Call the original function
    return orig_PyUnicode_Format(format, args);
}

static int hook_PyUnicode_Format() {
    funchook_t *funchook = funchook_create();
    if (funchook == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Get the address of the original PyUnicode_Format function
    orig_PyUnicode_Format = (PyObject *(*)(PyObject *, PyObject *))PyUnicode_Format;

    // Prepare the hook
    if (funchook_prepare(funchook, (void **)&orig_PyUnicode_Format, (void *)hooked_PyUnicode_Format) != 0) {
        funchook_destroy(funchook);
        return -1;
    }

    // Install the hook
    if (funchook_install(funchook, 0) != 0) {
        funchook_destroy(funchook);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Module initialization function
static PyModuleDef moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "myhook",
    "A module that hooks PyUnicode_Format",
    -1,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_myhook(void) {
    if (hook_PyUnicode_Format() != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
}


setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    data_files=[
        ('lib', ['funchook/libfunchook.so.2']),  # 将库文件安装到lib目录
    ],
    name="test_module",
    include_package_data=True,
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            name="myhook",
            sources=["spammify.c"],
            include_dirs=include_dirs,
            library_dirs=include_dirs,
            libraries=["funchook"],
            runtime_library_dirs=['$ORIGIN/lib']

        ),
    ]
)



import myhook


print("as{0}".format("a"))

I use PyCharm, and when I start it normally, it doesn't work. However, when I debug the program to start it, it can output normally and print the following content on the console
asa
PyUnicode_Format is called with format: IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS %s

PyUnicode_Format is called with format: LIBRARY_ROOTS %s

Who can help me，I can't find examples on the Internet
